# Multiple TOCs with different sorting

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm new to LaTeX as I'm trying to figure out if it's a viable for my need.

I'm hoping to create a songbook using \includepdf, but I would like several different table of contents based on different criteria for each item/chapter: simple page order, by composer, by title, and by liturgical season. I could define these for each piece in the LaTeX file manually.

Can someone point me to the right package and method to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Entries in the normal Table of Contents (ToC) are not sorted, they are ordered according to their occurrence in the text. I think that what you might be after is a regular ToC of song titles together with various indexes sorted on composer, liturgical season, or others (first lines?). The `memoir` class provides for multiple indexes but there are other ways to create them as well.

Comment: I could possibly do the other categories as indexes, yes. So, I'll have multiple indexes where the keywords are composers and titles/first lines. How should I specify the liturgical season for each piece that will be included in the index, but not printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Peter- multiple indexes was the way to go. Here's a demo of what I came up with.

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper, titlepage]{book}

\title{Florigeum Portense}
\author{Bodenschatz}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeindex[name=comp,title=Index of composers,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=titles,title=Index of titles,columns=2]
\makeindex[name=lit,title=Liturgical season,columns=1]

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{First Piece}
\index[comp]{Gallus!GallusTitle}
\index[titles]{GallusTitle}
\index[lit]{2@Easter!GallusTitle}
\includepdf[pages=-]{one.pdf}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Second Piece}
\index[comp]{Lassus, Orlando!LassusTitle}
\index[titles]{LassusTitle}
\index[lit]{1@Christmas!LassusTitle}
\includepdf[pages=-]{two.pdf}


\printindex[titles]
\printindex[comp]
\printindex[lit]

\end{document}
```